# codeigniter session exists before taken

Tags: php, codeigniter, sessionid

While my project run for the first time the following function works:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata(array('value'=> $this->session->session_id));

    $ses_id=$this->session->userdata('value');  

    $info['session_id']=$ses_id;

    $this->load->view('index',$info);
}
```

Now if I print the $ses_id with `echo $ses_id` then it shows the session id. But if I omit the first line in the function body and the function becomes like the following code:

```
public function index()
{   
    echo $ses_id=$this->session->userdata('value'); 

    $info['session_id']=$ses_id;

    $this->load->view('index',$info);
}
```

Then it also shows the session id though it has not been taken yet. What could be the problem here that before I take the session id it appears?

Comment: It seem you misunderstand about `session`. Usually, it will be store until you close the browser or expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concept is not clear regarding **session**. So first of all you need to study and understand how session will work. Please check this [Codeigniter Session](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) for better understanding.

JFI, in codeigniter the session data array included 4 items by default:

1. session_id
2. ip_address
3. user_agent
4. last_activity

Once you have store the value in session and you omit the first line and definitely it will shown value in **$sess_id** b/c session value has been stored in browser and it will not remove until you clear/destroy/expire the session.